# How do I reference another page from current page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I know how to navigate between pages, but how do I change a property from PageA while being in PageB?

I DON'T WANT TO MAKE A NEW INSTANCE OF PageA because PageA must register the changes made from all the other pages, by the user so... my application must have only 1 PageA. The unique instance of PageA that I want to reference is being defined in xaml and it's Class name is WorkoutRoutineTab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PumpFit"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="PumpFit.TrainingMainPage"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
             BarBackgroundColor="#2C2C2C"
             SelectedTabColor="White"
             UnselectedTabColor="#9F9F9F">   

    <local:WorkoutRoutineTab x:Name="routineListPage" x:FieldModifier="public" IconImageSource="muscleIcon.png"/>
    <local:ExerciseBankTab IconImageSource="searchIcon.png"/>
    <local:CronometerTab IconImageSource="timerIcon.png"/>

</TabbedPage>
```

**PS**: *I gave a name (x:Name) to the instance wishing that I could use it in the other Class, but it doesn't work, the instance is only being recognize by the .cs file of that .xaml file*

In addition I will provide the class page from which I want to change the WorkoutRoutineTab's properties: [Deleted Image]

**OBSERVATIONS**:

1. I thought that making the relation from this Page to the WorkoutRoutineTab Page by defining a WorkoutRoutineTab attribute in this class would do the thing, but that would imply to instantiate a new WorkoutRoutineTab class object because I don't even know how to find the WorkoutRoutineTab page instance in the NavigationStack, and even if I knew how. The NavigationStack is read only so I could not change it's properties.
2. Passing information using the class constructors is not an option because those two classes are pretty far away in the NavigationStack so I'm not even considering doing that.

### **EDIT:**

I have used the MessageCenter to send and subscribe to messages so I can pass the information that I need, but know the WorkoutRoutineTab Page (PageA) is indifferent to the changes that I have made.

I will explain more in detail what is my problem know:

I want to populate a ListView that is in the WorkoutRoutineTab Page by setting it's ItemSource property to a generic type List<> but when I return to the WorkoutRoutineTab the new items are not being added to the ListView. Here is the new WorkoutRoutineTab Class definition in both xaml and cs:

the XAML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PumpFit"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:PumpFit.Entity"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="PumpFit.WorkoutRoutineTab"
             Title="Workout"
             BackgroundColor="#343434">

    <StackLayout x:Name="routineStackLayout" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20,10">
        <ListView x:Name="routineListView" x:FieldModifier="public" SeparatorColor="#2C2C2C" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="2*,*" ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" FontFamily="Ubuntu"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TimesDone}" TextColor="#9F9F9F" FontSize="Body" FontFamily="Ubuntu"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TimesDone}" TextColor="#9F9F9F" FontSize="Body" FontFamily="Ubuntu"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
            <Button x:Name="newRoutineButton" Text="New routine" FontSize="Body" FontFamily="Geo" 
                BackgroundColor="#2C2C2C" TextColor="#87BC72" Clicked="NewRoutineButton_Clicked" />
    </StackLayout> 
    

</ContentPage>
```

And the cs file with with the MessageCenter.send() method:

```
using PumpFit.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace PumpFit
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class WorkoutRoutineTab : ContentPage
    {
        public List<Routine> Routines { get; set; }

        public WorkoutRoutineTab()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            routineListView.ItemsSource = Routines;
        }

        private async void NewRoutineButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<WorkoutRoutineTab>(this, "FillRoutines");
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ExerciseBankTab() { Title = "" });
        }
    }
}
```

Also the other class in which I use the MessageCenter.Subscribe() method:

```
public partial class AddExercisePage : ContentPage
    {
        public Exercise newExercise;

        public AddExercisePage(Exercise selectedExercise)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            newExercise = selectedExercise; 

            nameLabel.Text = newExercise.Name;
        }

        private async void CancelButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }

        private void AddButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(setsEntry.Text != null && repsEntry.Text != null && restTimePicker.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(setsEntry.Text, out int sets) && int.TryParse(repsEntry.Text, out int reps) && sets > 0 && reps > 0)
                {
                    List<Exercise> newExerciseList = new List<Exercise>()
                    {
                        new Exercise(newExercise.Name, newExercise.MuscleGroup, newExercise.ExerciseDifficulty, newExercise.Equipment, newExercise.Description, sets, reps, restTimePicker.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    };

                    //HERE IS WHERE I WISH TO CHANGE THE OTHER CLASS PROPERTIES

                    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<WorkoutRoutineTab>(this, "FillRoutines", (messageSender) =>
                    {
                        messageSender.Routines = new List<Routine>() { new Routine(routineNameEntry.Text, newExerciseList) };
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayAlert("ERROR", "You must only enter positive numbers", "OK");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("ERROR", "All fields must be set to add the exercise to the routine", "OK");
            }
        }
    }
```

**ANYWAY I APPRECIATE ALL THE HELP THAT YOU COULD PROVIDE! :)**

Comment: You would use pub/sub messaging or an event aggregator (depending on what you are using)

Comment: @TheGeneral could you elaborate a litlle bit more please i'm new in the business

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: AddExercise page inherits the class ContentPage.  So you want to inherit the ContentPage if new page is different from AddExcercisePage.

Comment: Images of code are not searchable or accessible and they don't make it easy for people trying to help you copy the code so that they can work with it. Please either augment the images with the code they contain, or replace them with the code that they contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is MessagingCenter achievement, I used two pages. Page1 have the label, when navigate to the page2. then back to the page1, we use MessagingCenter to transfer data.

Here is running GIF.

[image]

First of all, we used following code to send information in the page2. I send the "test" from Page2.

```
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page2 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            MessagingCenter.Send<App, string>(App.Current as App, "OpenPage", "test");
        }
    }
```

We can subscript it in the Page1.

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(App.Current, "OpenPage", (snd, arg) =>
            {
                MyLabel.Text = arg;
            });
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot! I think I'm going the right way, I don't even knew of the MessageCenter existance, but I alredy have called the subscribe and send methods and the page in wich I want to change the properties is not changing. Actually I want to start to populate a ListView that is in the page that sends the message could you help me trying to find what's the problem @Leo Lu ?

Comment: The collection that i'm setting the ListViews's ItemSource Property is a generic List<> that contains a one of my custom Classses called Routine I will add a edit section to my question

Comment: I notice your `MessagingCenter.Send<WorkoutRoutineTab>(this, "FillRoutines");`, you do not send any thing if you use above code. you need add a attribute (workoutRoutineTab is a object)  `MessagingCenter.Send<WorkoutRoutineTab>(this, "FillRoutines",workoutRoutineTab);`, And in your `MessageCenter.Subscribe()`, you get the workoutRoutineTab from the `WorkoutRoutineTab` page, why you give him a new data?

Comment: Nevermind @Leon Lu I figure it out, you were right about this last comment. I was sending the message where I should subscribe to it and I was subscribing to it where I should send it. I have messed up everything but after reading the documentation of the MessagingCenter I have finally understood. Thanks a lot brother I'll accept your answer because without the MessagingCenter I will be very stuck!

Answer (score 0):

If you PageA is like this

```
public class PageA : ContentPage {
    public ICommand GoToPageB => new Command(async () => {
        var pageB = new PageB();

        pageB.Callback => (message) => {
            // you can handle callback from PageB inside PageA
            if (message != null) {}
        };

        await Navigation.PushAsync(pageB);
    });
}
```

and your PageB is like

```
public class PageB : ContentPage {
    public event Action<int> Callback;

    public override void OnAppearing() {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Callback?.Invoke("PageB is appeared.");
    }
}
```

you can evaluate the value from `Callback` event and you still have reference to PageA inside the callback event